# Использование Telegram Api

Tags: php, telegram

Подскажите, как использовать `Telegram Api` на `PHP`? Как вызывать функции?

Очень много примеров использования `telegram api` для бота, а как использовать обычное `api telegram`?

Зарегистрировал приложение, получил `api_id` и `api_hash`.
Хочу получить все сообщения [группы](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory).

Как вызвать этот метод, не понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте библиотеку [MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto). Документация отвратительная, но лучше, чем ничего. Автор русскоязычный, иногда подсказывает.

```
$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API();
$MadelineProto->session = 'mySession.madeline';
if (isset($number)) { // Login as a user
    $MadelineProto->phone_login($number);
    $code = readline('Enter the code you received: '); // Or do this in two separate steps in an HTTP API
    $MadelineProto->complete_phone_login($code);
}

$messages_Messages = $MadelineProto->messages->getHistory(['peer' => InputPeer, 'offset_id' => int, 'offset_date' => int, 'add_offset' => int, 'limit' => int, 'max_id' => int, 'min_id' => int, 'hash' => int, ]);
```

---

Если кому-то интересно, почему документация лучше официальной - Мадлен поддерживает 73 layer(версию API), а в официальных доках последний описанный - 18.

Answer (score 0):

MTProto работает через сокеты. В php нормально с сокетами работать «не легко». Поэтому лучше сразу через NodeJS работаете.